# In what case do you choose to create a static function rather than a dynamic function

Tags: php, function, dynamic, static

I would like to know in what case do you choose to use a static function rather than a dynamic. I clearly understand the difference between static and dynamic but: I was wondering whats the best practice when you create a new function and you can do both.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question - [When to use static modifier in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316800/when-to-use-static-modifier-in-php)