# When a method should be static? PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

I'm using PHP as my programming language. I really don't understand the use of static method and variables.

1. When a methold should be static?/ What methods should be static ?
2. How to identify what methold should be static?
3. Pros and Cons static method and variables ?

Thanks

Comment: statics are just a fancy way to group procedural code into a class. Except for very special cases, avoid them.

Comment: I don't why the hell they closed my questions? Looks like not knowing something is a crime :O

Comment: methods should be static when you trying to mask your procedural code with language tools meant for object oriented programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object

```
<?php class Foo {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        // ...
    } }

$classname = 'Foo'; $classname::aStaticMethod(); // ( PHP 5.3.0) ?>
```

"it can be initiated with out an OBJECT"

Comment: why do we create objects when we can go on calling function with :: ?(given if we make every function static)

Comment: nice question :) when you use static keyword to a method > you couple yourself directly to the class. It's impossible to use polymorphism and inheritance , giving importance to Object is what OOP paradigm is.

Comment: `A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object` this is flat out wrong

Answer (score 2):

Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).

When you are working on a large OOP based project, you’ll no doubt be working with many classes (both parent and child classes). An unfortunate consequence of this is that in order to access elements from different classes, they must manually be passed through each class (or worse, storing an instance in a global variable). This can be painstakingly frustrating and can lead to messy code and overall bad project design. Thankfully, static elements are accessible from any context (i.e. anywhere in your script), so you can access these methods without needing to pass an instance of the class from object to object.

also check this [Does static method in PHP have any difference with non-static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439036/does-static-method-in-php-have-any-difference-with-non-static-method#answer-2439053)

Comment: why functions without static keyword are possible to access with scope resolution operator ?

Comment: please check [Scope Resolution Operator (::)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Comment: why do we create objects when we can go on calling function with :: ?(given if we make every function static)

Comment: @Dasun, if you make every object static then their isnt any reason to create object. applied that you are not using pubic instance variables.

Comment: is it a bad practice to make every variable and method static ?

Comment: @Dasun Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316800/when-to-use-static-modifier-in-php

Answer (score 2):

A method should be static when it is not bound to instance variables. If it is doing plane processing and taking all the variables from function inputs. It can be marked as static.

Its advantage is you need not to create instances to invoke functionality and hence saves memory.

Comment: why functions without static keyword are possible to access with scope resolution operator ?